# SVG not rendering in Firefox (latest version)

Tags: css, html, firefox, svg

Looked at other answers on StackOverflow and tried changing the `<g></g>, <clientpath/>,` etc but no luck. The SVG doesnt render in Firefox (v 36.0.4)

Here is the html code:

```
<td role="gridcell">
    <span class="entity-chart k-chart" data-role="chart" style="position: relative;">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

        <defs>
            <clipPath id="fd1ba3a5-b043-4aea-bf23-6263c8c364dd">
                <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke="#000" d="M14 5 L 594 5 594 19 14 19Z"/>
            </clipPath>
            <linearGradient gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" y2="1" x2="0" y1="0" x1="0" id="e6d64ff2-2146-408e-b1ed-924e26e7da59">
                <stop style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0;" offset="0"/>
                <stop style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0.3;" offset="0.25"/>
                <stop style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0;" offset="1"/>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>

        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="none" d="M0 0 L 600 0 600 25 0 25Z"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="none" d="M14 5 L 594 5 594 19 14 19Z"/>
            <g><g/>
            <g/>
            <g><g/>
        </g>
        <g clip-path="url(#fd1ba3a5-b043-4aea-bf23-6263c8c364dd)">
            <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
                <path fill-opacity="1" fill="#0055cc" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0044a3" d="M14.5 9.5 L 409.5 9.5 409.5 15.5 14.5 15.5Z"/>
                <path fill="url(#e6d64ff2-2146-408e-b1ed-924e26e7da59)" stroke="none" d="M14.5 9.5 L 409.5 9.5 409.5 15.5 14.5 15.5Z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text fill-opacity="1" fill="#000" stroke="none" y="12" x="5" style="font:12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <tspan/>
            </text>
        </g>
        </g>
        <g/>
        <g/>
        <g/>
        <g opacity="1">
            <path fill="none" stroke="none" d="M413.455 9.2 L 446.455 9.2 446.455 14.8 413.455 14.8Z"/>
            <text fill-opacity="1" fill="#000" stroke="none" y="15.999999999999998" x="417.45454545454544" style="font:11px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <tspan>75 %</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
        </g>

        </svg>
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Your `<g>` elements are severely mismatched. You open one, then you open a second one, then close the second one, and then you have a self closing one, and then you have another set of opening/closing tags, and then you close the first `<g>` element. But then you open another one and then close it *twice*. See here for an easier-to-follow representation: http://jsfiddle.net/4auheggj/

Comment: I prettified the code-soup so you can see multiple `<g>` misuse, as @TylerH explained, waiting for review approval.

Comment: @DeDee I should have done that first as it let's the problem shine though fairly clearly, lol.

Comment: Thank you @TylerH. This markup was auto-generated by Telerik's Kendo Chart (chart.kendoChart({})). Can't do anything with it. I will upgrade to latest Telerik version and see if it resolves the error.

Comment: @dotnetter Sure, it's understandable. Though when asking questions with large amounts of code, it's best to try and prettify it in your question to make it readable. That likely would have solved your question before you even pressed "Ask" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your svg code has errors with the group  tags not being properly opened/closed. Additionally, there are a couple that seem to be mistyped (`<g/>`). The code below is valid so you can use as a reference.

```
<td role="gridcell">
  <span class="entity-chart k-chart" data-role="chart" style="position: relative;">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 1500 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1500 1000" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <path fill="none" d="M0,0h600v25H0V0z"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M14,5h580v14H14V5z"/>
      <g>
        <g>
          <defs>
            <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="14" y="5" width="580" height="14"/>
          </defs>
          <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
          </clipPath>
          <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
            <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
              <path fill="#0055CC" stroke="#0044A3" d="M14.5,9.5h395v6h-395V9.5z"/>

                <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0.5" y1="1000" x2="0.5" y2="999" gradientTransform="matrix(395 0 0 -6 14.5 6009.5)">
                <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
                <stop offset="0.25" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.3"/>
                <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0"/>
              </linearGradient>
              <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" d="M14.5,9.5h395v6h-395V9.5z"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g>
        <path fill="none" d="M413.5,9.2h33v5.6h-33V9.2z"/>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 417.4546 16)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="11">75 %</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: This may solve the problem, but you don't go into *any* detail on what the errors are and how your answer solves them. Please consider adding details to help explain the wall of code.

Comment: @TylerH I did not point out the errors because. as you pointed out in your comment, the tags are a mess. With a working piece of code, he can then compare and see what was wrong. I find this is the most efficient process for me but my apologies if my response was not clear enough.

Comment: @JoeConlin - as I posted the comment, I will upgrade the Telerik kendo to latest and see if the autogen mark up of KendoChart gets fixed.

Comment: @JoeConlin Yeah, if his code can be prettified to look like yours then a side-by-side comparison might be helpful. Though I didn't mean necessarily a "line-by-line" explanation. Just something a little more descriptive than "your code has errors. use this". Something like "you have extra closing tags in your code. I've removed them in the code below:"